# Xcode Bots fail with linker error

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, cocoapods

I'am using OS X Server to build my iOS projects and distribute them. Since I'am using Cocoapods for dependancy management, I've created pre-build action to run `pod install`, which succeeds and correctly installs the pods. 
However, the actual integration process fails with a linker error which is telling me it can't find the pods library:

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-redacted
```

Does anyone have an idea, why this happens?